# Why does the following expression tree not compile unless we use a block?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, expression, expression-trees

I have the following expression tree:

```
var collection = Expression.Variable(typeof(string[]), "testVar");
        Expression[] arrayElements = new[] { Expression.Constant("helloWorld") };
        var arrayInitialization = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(string), arrayElements);
        var body = Expression.Assign(collection, arrayInitialization);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<string[]>>(body).Compile();
```

It throws an error at the final expression, about "testVar" being out of scope, unless I change the return statement to the following:

```
return Expression.Lambda<Func<string[]>>(Expression.Block(
            typeof(string[]), new[] { collection }, body)).Compile();
```

Could someone explain why that is so? And if there is an alternative to not using a block, but still having a variable defined in the expression tree?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? `() => {var testVar = new [] {"helloWorld"}; }`? But such expression doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Evk basically what you wrote, I know it doesn't make sense, I just want to get my head around why it requires a block when a variable is involved, and if its actually possible to avoid it? Or are blocks ALWAYS a requirement when variables are involved? Meaning our `Expression.Lambda` will always need to use an `Expression.Block`?

Comment: Yes if you want to declare a local variable inside expression tree - you have to use a block. There is no "main block" there, because regular lambda is something like `() => DoSomething()` (no curly bracers), but if you want to define a local variable you'll do something like `() => { var testVal = ... }` (curly bracers defining a block).